# How can we give ID based on consecutive dates

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need an unique ID for consecutive dates

source table

| SNAPSHOT_DATE | CHANNEL | CASE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-19 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-20 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-23 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-24 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-25 | web | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-19 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-21 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-22 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 52LnlJQAS |
| 2022-10-26 | phone | 52LnlJQAS |
| 2022-10-20 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-24 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |
| 2022-10-25 | phone | 521nzT3HQA |

I tried this query

```
Select snapshot_date, channel,case_id
,case_id||channel||Dateadd('day', -(row_number() over (partition by case_id, channel order by snapshot_date)), snapshot_date+1) as ID
From test
```

got output

| SNAPSHOT_DATE | CHANNEL | CASE_ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-19 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-20 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-21 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-22 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-24 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-19 |
| 2022-10-25 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-19 |
| 2022-10-18 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-19 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-20 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-23 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-20 |
| 2022-10-24 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-20 |
| 2022-10-25 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-20 |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 52LnlJQAS | 52LnlJQASphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-26 | phone | 52LnlJQAS | 52LnlJQASphone2022-10-25 |

expected output

| SNAPSHOT_DATE | CHANNEL | CASE_ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-19 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-20 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-21 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-22 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-24 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-24 |
| 2022-10-25 | phone | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAphone2022-10-24 |
| 2022-10-18 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-19 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-20 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-23 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-24 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-25 | web | 521nzT3HQA | 521nzT3HQAweb2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-18 | phone | 52LnlJQAS | 52LnlJQASphone2022-10-18 |
| 2022-10-26 | phone | 52LnlJQAS | 52LnlJQASphone2022-10-26 |

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical problem of searching for gaps.

Something like this should work:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT SNAPSHOT_DATE::date AS SNAPSHOT_DATE, CHANNEL, CASE_ID
      FROM (VALUES  ('2022-10-18',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-19',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-20',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-23',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-24',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-25',  'web',      '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-18',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-19',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-21',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-22',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-18',  'phone',    '52LnlJQAS' ),
                    ('2022-10-26',  'phone',    '52LnlJQAS' ),
                    ('2022-10-20',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-24',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA'),
                    ('2022-10-25',  'phone',    '521nzT3HQA')) T(SNAPSHOT_DATE, CHANNEL, CASE_ID)
), grp AS (
    SELECT SNAPSHOT_DATE, CHANNEL, CASE_ID
         , MIN(SNAPSHOT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_ID, CHANNEL) AS MIN_SNAPSHOT_DATE
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_ID, CHANNEL ORDER BY SNAPSHOT_DATE) 
           + DATEDIFF(DAY, SNAPSHOT_DATE, MIN_SNAPSHOT_DATE) AS DIFF
      FROM sample_data
)
SELECT SNAPSHOT_DATE, CHANNEL, CASE_ID
     , CASE_ID || CHANNEL || MIN(SNAPSHOT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_ID, CHANNEL, DIFF) AS ID
  FROM grp
 ORDER BY CASE_ID, CHANNEL, SNAPSHOT_DATE;
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine, unique id for consecutive dates

Answer (score 0):

The following query solves your issue. It utilizes lag for detecting non consecutive dates within a group of channel and case_id. Further a rolling sum is employed to create a flag, which is used for grouping in order to get the oldest snapshot date within a consecutive date range.

```
select snapshot_date
, channel
, case_id
 -- get the minimum date over channel, case_id and the group flag 
, case_id ||channel || min(snapshot_date) over (partition by channel, case_id, grp_flag) as compound_id 
from (
    select sum(non_cons_dt) over( partition by channel, case_id order by snapshot_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp_flag --rolling sum as group flag, will increment on non consecutive date  
     , x.*
    from (
        select 
           iff(dateadd('day', 1, lag(snapshot_date) over(partition by channel, case_id order by snapshot_date)) = snapshot_date, 0, 1) as non_cons_dt -- set 1 if there is a non consecutive date within the group
         , snapshot_date
         , channel
         , case_id 
       from test
    ) x 
) y
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine, unique id for consecutive dates

Comment: Would you mind doing a benchmark with the two proposed solutions and write the results in a comment? Thanks